# NSString's enumerateSubstrings doesn't include symbols

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, enumeration

When using NSString's `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` with the options set as `NSStringEnumerationByWords` it doesn't include symbols such as `/*` or `//` which should be treated similarly to words as they  are seperated by spaces.

I also tried using `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` but it seems to do exactly the same thing even without this option, it simply goes through every single letter.

Is their no way to enumerate through every substring separated by a space? It sounds so simple by no way to do is provided to do this using `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:`.

**EDIT**

I was also using the option `NSEnumerationReverse` to got through the substrings backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for something like this.  It's sort of the long way around, but if the `enumerate...` messages aren't doing it for you, it might be worth looking at.

For example, you could do something like

```
NSString *output = nil;
NSCharacterSet *whitespaceCharSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];

NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:someString];

// should skip leading whitespace and read everything up to the next whitespace
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:whitespaceCharSet intoSring:&output];

[scanner release];
```

Sort of a crude example, but the documentation for NSScanner is fairly simple.

**Edit:**  Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
NSString *someString = <...>; // get your string somehow

NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
NSArray *components = [someString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet];

[components
 enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse
 usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        // do stuff
    }];
```

Comment: I was considering using `NSScanner` but (what I forgot to mention in the question is that) I need to do this in reverse. For which I was using the option `NSEnumerationReverse` and as far as I can see there is no way to use `NSScanner` in reverse.

Comment: @Joshua Well, it's ugly, but you could reverse the string, then for each substring, reverse that as well.  Not pretty, though.  Could also just iterate over the characters yourself and pick out substrings, though that's not much fun.

Comment: Looked into it a bit, added an alternative that should do the same as the `enumerate…` messages without the mess of using `NSScanner`.

Comment: Hmm… looks promising. Only one thing, it provides no way to get the range of the substring within the original string.